# How to keep the application running when the last window is closed?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a very basic GUI project in Qt (using c++) and want to be able to close the main window in my program without the program quitting all the way. By default, it will exit when the main window is closed. How to prevent that?

Answer (score 5):

Set the `QApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed` property to false:

```
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you still need your window to exist, you would probably like to reimplement your closeEvent method like this:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{

    hide();
    event->ignore();
}
```

or use `QGuiApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false)`

If you want to perform some pre-exit operation as saving settings, connect some slot doing what you want to `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()`